# C# Entities Tree Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, model, tree

On a blog page,
**Subcategories will be linked to the main Category and will be articles of subcategories. Do you think the model structure is correct?**

I will develop it with Asp.net Core and EntityFrameworkCore architecture.

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }


    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
--------------------------------------
public class SubCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }


    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}
----------------------------------------------
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set;}

    public string ArticleTitle { get; set; }

    public string ArticleContent { get; set; }

    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }

    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is changing the category model to [Self-referencing relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51308913/7086678)

These links are helpful for `Self-referencing` 
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34439573/7086678) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9955491/7086678)

```cs
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public Category Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ArticleCategories> ArticleCategories { get; set; }
}
```

then create [`Many-to-Many`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) relationship between `Article` and `Category` class

```cs
public class ArticleCategories
{
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public Article Article { get; set; }
}
```

**Article** model

```cs
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set;}

    public string ArticleTitle { get; set; }

    public string ArticleContent { get; set; }

    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ArticleCategories> ArticleCategories { get; set; }
}
```

in this case any `Article` can have many `Category` and any `Category` can used for many `Articles`